# Soma consecutiva de uma coluna em SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Queria calcular os dados de uma tabela más da seguinte maneira

tenho uma coluna de preços

> 100  140  300 200

queria gerar uma segunda coluna que faria uma soma consecutiva da tabela anterior

> 100 240 540 740

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui fazer com Python uma logica mais não sei fazer em SQL

Comment: você quer adicionar uma coluna com soma a uma tabela existente, ou você quer criar uma tabela com uma coluna que repete o primeiro registro, caso não exista um e soma com anterior caso já exista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso, utilize o `OVER` sobre a função `SUM`. O OVER fará com que o SUM se aplique sob uma condição, que no caso será todos os números até o "offset" atual.

```
SELECT preço, SUM(preço) OVER (ORDER BY preço) AS "SOMA CONSECUTIVA" FROM valores;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fadb/31).